# Passing an array to another method and copying it

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to pass an array from one method to another method and then copy the contents of that array into a new array. I am having trouble with the syntax to accomplish that task. 
Does anyone have some reference material that I could read about this topic or maybe a helpful tip that I could apply?

I apologize if this is a noob question, but I have only been messing with Java for 3-4 weeks part time.

I know that Java uses pass by value, but what where I'm getting lost is...should I invoke the sourceArray before copying it to the targetArray?

My goal here is not to be just handed an answer, I need to understand WHY.

Thanks...in advance.

```
package cit130mhmw08_laginess;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CIT130MHMW08_Laginess 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the total number of dealers: ");
    int numDealers = input.nextInt();
    numDealers = numberOfDealers(numDealers);

    System.out.printf("%nPlease enter the required data for each of your dealers:");
    dataCalculation(numDealers);

}//main

//METHOD 1
public static int numberOfDealers(int dealers)
{
    int results;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(dealers < 0 || dealers > 30)
    {
        System.out.printf("%nEnter a valid number of dealers: ");
        dealers = input.nextInt();  
    }
    results = dealers;
    return results;

}//number of dealers methods

//METHOD 2
public static void dataCalculation(int data)
{
    String[] dealerNames = new String[data];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("%nEnter the names of the dealers:%n ");

        for(int i = 0; i < data; i++)
        {
            String names =input.nextLine();
            dealerNames[i]= names;
        }

    int[] dealerSales = new int[data];
    System.out.printf("%nEnter their sales totals: %n");

        for(int i = 0; i < data; i++)
        {
            int sales = input.nextInt();
            dealerSales[i] = sales;
        }


    for(int i = 0; i < data; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(" " + dealerNames[i]);
        System.out.println(" " + dealerSales[i]);
    }
    //gather the required input data. 
    //Perform the appropriate data validation here.

}//data calculations

//METHOD 3
public static int commission(int data)
{
    //Create array
    int[] commissionRate = new int[dealerSales]; 

    //Copy dealerSales array into commissionRate
    System.arraycopy(dealerSales, 0, commissionRate, 0, dealerSales.length);

    //calculate the commission array.
    //$1 - $5,000...8%
    //$5,001 to $15,000...15%
    //$15,001...20%

    //

}//commission method 
}//class
```

Comment: Your program gave me a compilation error. The dealerSales in commission() cannot be resolved. This is because the dealerSales is not accessible throughout the class since it is a variable of the method dataCalculation() rather than the class. Suggestion would be to declare dealerSales as private member of class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy an array, you can use the [`Arrays.copyOf(origin, length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) method. It takes 2 arguments, first one is the array from which the data is supposed to be copied and second is the length of the new array, and import java.util.Arrays.

-See the link for more info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)